# MS Access Year(Date() Function

Tags: sql, date, ms-access

I'm trying to create a MS Access query to give me a count of records by month for the current year. The field with the date is text and the date is in the format of `YYYY-MM`. Everything I've read says to use `Year(myDate) = 2014`, but I don't get any results. I've also tried `Year(Date())`, but again no results. Any ideas on what to do to get this query to run?

Comment: well, you said it yourself, that column is a text not a date (even if it's storing a "date"). Did you try `LEFT(myDate,4)`?

Comment: @Lamak, Does ms-access not perform implicit conversions?

Comment: @Sev09 I wouldn't know, but even if it did, to perform a conversion from a string to a date, the string should have to be in a date format, which isn't the case in this question (`YYYY-MM` isn't a date, it's missing the day part)

Answer (score 3):

One way to get "a count of records by month for the current year" would be

```sql
SELECT YearMonth, COUNT(*) AS RecordCount
FROM YourTable
WHERE YearMonth LIKE Year(Date()) & "*"
GROUP BY YearMonth
```

where [YearMonth] is your `YYYY-MM` text column.